# Function declaration in React Components matters?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

Here is my question: What is the difference between these two declarations:
[image]

Whats the matter if I declare it on top of my component and what if within it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: include the code from the image in the question

Comment: Edited to display image, but please do not include screenshots of code in SO questions. Add the code directly and surround with code ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that are created inside `class` components are usually referred to as methods.

If your function doesn't depend on class instance properties `state` or `props` and is independent of the component you can define that function outside the class.

But if your function need access to the class state, prop or any other class methods, you'll need to define it within the class component so you can use `this.state` or `this.props`.

So, thumb rule would be that if you need any access of the class component instance i.e. **`this`** within your function, you will need to define the function inside the component.